# Usando INSERT ou UPDATE em uma PROCEDURE para atualizar uma tabela - ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, procedure

Boa tarde Senhores

Criei uma tabela e uma procedure para se relacionar com a tabela inserindo quando não e atualizando quando houver, mas não esta funcionando e não consigo identificar o problema. Por favor, poderiam ajudar?

Quando faço a execução da procedure dá como executado com sucesso mas não insere na tabela.

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE RRPTREPORT_PARAM
  2      (
  3         CODCOLIGADA integer Not NULL,
  4         IDRELATORIO integer Not NULL,
  5         MES varchar(2),
  6         ANO varchar(4)
  7      );

Tabela criada.

SQL>    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_RRPTREPORT_PARAM(
  2        vCODCOLIGADA INTEGER,
  3        vIDRELATORIO INTEGER,
  4        vMES CHAR,
  5        vANO CHAR) is
  6      begin
  7          merge into RRPTREPORT_PARAM t1
  8     USING (SELECT * FROM RRPTREPORT_PARAM WHERE CODCOLIGADA=vCODCOLIGADA and IDRELATORIO=vIDRELATORIO)t2
  9             ON (t1.CODCOLIGADA = t2.CODCOLIGADA and t1.IDRELATORIO = t2.IDRELATORIO)
 10          WHEN MATCHED THEN
 11            UPDATE
 12               SET MES=vMES, ANO=vANO
 13     WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
 14      insert (CODCOLIGADA, IDRELATORIO, MES, ANO)
 15                 values (vCODCOLIGADA, vIDRELATORIO, vMES, vANO);
 16     end;
 17  /

Procedimento criado.

SQL> EXECUTE SP_RRPTREPORT_PARAM(1,2222,'08','2023');
Procedimento PL/SQL concluÝdo com sucesso.

SQL> SELECT * FROM RRPTREPORT_PARAM;
nÒo hß linhas selecionadas
```

Comment: rpz, pelo que entendi do sql, o motivo é porque a tua tabela `RRPTREPORT_PARAM` está vazia. Então nunca será executado o que está na cláusula `ON` do merge.